I am unable to authenticate with polkit, blocking me from running certain services as my admin user (such as docker)
Fedora 40, Cinnamon
I am currently only able to start docker as root. When I attempt to start it as my local user with my password, or with the root password they are not accepted. The following logs appear:
Dec 04 12:15:56 laptop cinnamon[3994]: JS LOG: polkitAuthenticationAgent: Received 2 identities that can be used for authentication. Only considering the first one.
Dec 04 12:15:57 laptop unix_chkpwd[41240]: password check failed for user (gnome-initial-setup)

Using root to view the GUI for users on my machine, my local user is the only user listed.
According to the polkit rules config being in the wheel group should be sufficient to run pkexec commands.
My user is in the wheel group:
$ groups |grep wheel
**MYUSERNAME** wheel kvm tss libvirt docker

It isn't clear to me what two identities polkit is seeing. How can I update the password it is using or correct this issue otherwise? Any insight would be appreciated.
Edit:
It appears it is trying to auth to polkit with the user 'gnome-initial-setup', and my user is the second option. I can select my user authenticating using a text shell, but not in the GUI.
Edit#2:
I believe the issue is the 'gnome-initial-setup' user is a remnant of the original GNOME desktop that shipped with Fedora before I installed Cinnamon. It just isn't clear to me if I am safe to remove this user entirely.
